# Problem getting monlist from my ntp server

Tags: networking, server, ntp

I guys, I need to look at MONLIST of my NTP server but when I execute the command `ntpdc -n -c monlist` I get `***Server reports data not found` and I don't understand why because I think that my ntp.conf file should enable monlist. Here is my ntp.conf file

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

# Specify one or more NTP servers.

# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
# on 2011-02-08 (LP: #104525). See http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html for
# more information.

pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst


# Use Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback.
#pool ntp.ubuntu.com


# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
#restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
#restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1 notrust
restrict 192.168.3.0/24 notrust
restrict 192.168.2.0/24 notrust
resrict ::1 notrust

# Needed for adding pool entries


# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.3.3 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust

enable mode7
enalbe monitor

# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
disable auth
```

Network 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 are my private network that want to use to control the server. 
Any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 1):

Might be that "enable" is spelled wrong, ("enalbe monitor").

Comment: Reviewers: this is a valid answer given that there *is* a misspelling in the `ntp.conf` file that would prevent things from being enabled as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually figured out why this won't work. It is because any version of ntp server that is after v4.2.7p26(including v4.2.7p26) would not respond to monlist packet anymore.

Hope this helps.

reference: https://new.blog.cloudflare.com/understanding-and-mitigating-ntp-based-ddos-attacks/